# How to add cookies on IE using vc++

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-c++, cookies

I am using functions `InternetSetCookie` and `InternetGetCookie` (WININET APIs) but it returns error code `12006`. So is there any way to add cookies in Internet Explorer?

I am able to successfully add cookies on Google Chrome and Firefox Mozilla using sqlite database tools.

So is there similar way for IE to add cookies?

Comment: The return value from these functions is either true or false, so I'm assuming you called `GetLastError()` to get that value. You should use the error lookup tool to see what that error is.  What context are you calling these functions in?  I.e., what process?

Comment: Yes i did same and error code 12006 means ERROR_INTERNET_UNRECOGNIZED_SCHEME(The URL scheme could not be recognized or is not supported) But i can't get this error description.

Comment: I am calling these functions(i.e **InternetSetCookie** and **InternetGetCookie** ) under console base application...So is there any problem with that?

Comment: From the console should work; I was wondering if you had an integrity level issue.  Can you post some of your code?  Are you trying to set it for a non-http url?

Comment: `bRet = InternetSetCookieA("http://google.co.in", "PREF", "COOKIEVALUE;expires=Sat, 08-Jan-2014 00:00:00 GMT");
if (FALSE == bRet)
{
 printf("InternetSetCookie (%u)...FAILED.", GetLastError());
 return FALSE;
}

printf("Success");` So Its working fine But My Cookie is creating under **C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies** But i want to create under **C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies\Low**  folder.After reading on net reach to conclusion that low privilege applications create cookies in **LOW** folder & High privilege create under **Cookies** folder

Comment: @jeffamaphone Thank u very much for answering my questions and forgive me for bad formatting..

Comment: Yes, you'll need to start a low integrity process:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625960.aspx

Comment: Yes i started my application as low integrity process but it gives me error code 12004(Internal Error). So solution for my problem is only To call IESetProtectedModeCookie from BHO?  Is there other way to create cookies in **LOW** folder using normal console application? and Thanx once again jeffamaphone...

Comment: I'm not sure what your issue is.

Comment: See Its very simple i just want to create my cookies under **C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies\Low** folder using **InternetSetCookie** But my cookies are created under **C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies** ..

Comment: Oh no, I meant I don't know why its not working or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

That error code means that you are passing the cookie's URL in a wrong format. You must make sure that all passed URLs use a valid scheme, one that includes at least both the protocol and the domain. So, for example:

The URL `www.mydomain.com` is not valid, because it does not have the protocol.
The URL `http://www.myotherdomain.com` is valid, because it includes the protocol and the domain.

Please make sure you are passing the URLs in a correct format. I had the same problem until I found my URLs where missing the protocol.